# Ajax loading two exact id's on one page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I am loading dynamic page loads with AJAX... Like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#xxxxx").click(function(){    
      document.getElementById("contentAll").innerHTML = "";    
  $.ajax({
      url: "base_template.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      $("#contentAll").append(html);
    }
  });
});
```

My Problem is that this only loads one navigation section (#id). I have two on the page (one at the top that is of a drop down variety and one to the left that gets loaded when you are on that specific page.

How do I manage to load two ID's, I'm baffled...

**WDH**

Comment: What HTML is inside `base_template.html`? Also, what HTML is on the page where your Javascript is?

Comment: a large page to post, 600 lines long...

Comment: @WebDevHed:  That's why you'd only post the **relevant** html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to have to IDs on the same page with the same value.  You can switch to using a class name instead of an ID and let jQuery operate on both objects with that class name.

Instead of `<div id="contentAll"></div>`, you would have `<div class="contentFinal"></div>` and then you would use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
      url: "base_template.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      $(".contentFinal").append(html);   // append to both places
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your help @jfriend00, it worked like a charm. I am relatively new to the jQuery world, could you give me a hint on making the page fadein with what I have above?

Comment: Glad it worked.  In the spirit of SO, you should ask a new question about the fade.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. ID's should only exist **once**. If you have multiple items on a page you should change those IDs to classes.

Then just use the classes in jQuery instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
      url: "base_template.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      $(".navigation").append(html);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Problem is that I already have classes for the links in question... I really don't like stacking multiple classes but it seems I have no choice.

Comment: It's silly to not use multiple classes.  CSS was designed for that and any good CSS design will use multiple classes on lots of objects.  You should use multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<div class="contentAll" id="top"></div>
<div class="contentAll" id="bottom"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "base_template.html",
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      $(".contentAll").append(html);
    }
  });
});
```